# How to insert in to multiple tables using one query in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql

I have to insert in to 5 tables with multiple fields with single insert statement of mysql and how to do it in JDBC.
I'm unable to write in single statement, please provide me the syntax for inserting into multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

Write mysql procedures or functions to insert into database. and call procedure from java code.

for eg:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLE_PROCEDURE (IN a varchar(50),IN b varchar(50),IN c varchar(50))
BEGIN
    insert into SAMPLE_TABLE (A,B ,C ) values (a,b,c);
END
```